# How to filter everything under NAME for certain strings?

Tags: bash, awk

Here is an example test.txt file that I am currently using:

```
NAME                                                NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                               APP VERSION
app-education-content-creator-1651375038            ci          1           2022-05-01 03:28:36.824230864 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
app-education-content-creator-preview-2255856586    ci          1           2022-05-02 03:51:24.017628998 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
app-education-content-creator-preview-2255904996    ci          1           2022-05-02 03:58:50.959635169 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
ci-external-secrets                                 ci          2           2021-09-13 19:58:32.975711779 +0000 UTC deployed    kubernetes-external-secrets-3.1.0   3.1.0      
ci-flux                                             ci          7           2022-01-04 18:37:49.503585809 +0000 UTC deployed    flux-1.11.2                         1.24.1     
ci-helm-operator                                    ci          5           2021-08-24 04:12:49.836776337 +0000 UTC deployed    helm-operator-1.2.0                 1.2.0      
cortex-preview-850-game-cortex-server               ci          1           2022-05-04 12:51:35.725983628 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
cortex-preview-853-game-cortex-server               ci          1           2022-05-18 19:22:11.062215547 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.4.14          1.0.0      
istio-gateways                                      ci          4           2022-04-27 20:01:21.569001421 +0000 UTC deployed    istio-gateways-0.1.0                           
launcher-preview-90-game-launcher                   ci          1           2022-05-18 18:34:27.09314326 +0000 UTC  deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
loader-preview-415-game-launcher                    ci          1           2022-05-17 15:42:23.055718169 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
loader-preview-415-game-loader                      ci          1           2022-05-17 15:42:16.490564899 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
loader-preview-415-passthrough                      ci          1           2022-05-17 15:42:20.406590056 +0000 UTC deployed    istio-passthrough-0.1.4             1.8.3      
loader-preview-454-game-launcher                    ci          1           2022-04-29 13:56:41.144878095 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
loader-preview-454-game-loader                      ci          1           2022-04-29 13:56:35.559380733 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
loader-preview-454-passthrough                      ci          1           2022-04-29 13:56:38.359154911 +0000 UTC deployed    istio-passthrough-0.1.4             1.8.3      
loader-preview-458-game-launcher                    ci          1           2022-05-17 22:14:26.959236354 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
loader-preview-458-game-loader                      ci          1           2022-05-17 22:14:20.956443867 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.4.14          1.0.0      
loader-preview-458-passthrough                      ci          1           2022-05-17 22:14:24.043742858 +0000 UTC deployed    istio-passthrough-0.1.4             1.8.3      
math-preview-5305-feature-flag-api                  ci          1           2022-04-25 21:36:18.331495893 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
math-preview-5305-feature-flag-client               ci          1           2022-04-25 21:36:20.665011277 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
math-preview-5305-flags-redis                       ci          1           2022-04-25 21:35:45.851677929 +0000 UTC deployed    redis-15.4.2                        6.2.5      
math-preview-5305-game-client                       ci          1           2022-04-25 21:36:28.290028875 +0000 UTC deployed    prodigy-application-0.3.11          1.0.0      
math-preview-5305-game-cortex-server                ci          1           2022-04-
```

Currently this line of code outputs all of the helm release NAME's that are older than X amount of days (in the test case below X is 3):

```
getOldPreviews() {
  secondsUntilStale=$1
  helmReleaseList=$2
  echo " "
  echo "$helmReleaseList" |
  awk 'f;/NAME/{f=1}' | 
  awk -v today="$today" -v expiryTime="$secondsUntilStale" '{
      getPreviewDateEpoch = "gdate -d \""$4" "$5"\" +%s"
      getPreviewDateEpoch | getline previewCreationDate
      if(today - previewCreationDate > expiryTime){ 
        print $1
      }
  }'
}
```

Test case when X is 3:

```
Namespace is: ci
Days until stale: 3
Helm list file path: test.txt

 

Filtered previews older than  3  days
 
app-education-content-creator-1651375038
app-education-content-creator-preview-2255856586
app-education-content-creator-preview-2255904996
ci-external-secrets
ci-flux
ci-helm-operator
cortex-preview-850-game-cortex-server
istio-gateways
loader-preview-454-game-launcher
loader-preview-454-game-loader
loader-preview-454-passthrough
math-preview-5305-feature-flag-api
math-preview-5305-feature-flag-client
math-preview-5305-flags-redis
math-preview-5305-game-client
math-preview-5305-game-cortex-server
```

How do I make it so that I filter for the X amount of days AND certain releases such anything with "preview-", "-preview-" ?

Comment: What are the values of `$today` and `$secondsUntilStale` and `$helmReleaseList`? How does `X` come into the picture? There's no `X` in your code. The `echo | awk | awk` pipeline can be written as a single awk command, but I have questions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the echo | awk | awk pipeline could be written as a single command ?

Comment: I demonstrated it in my answer. The main bit is `NR > 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to filter the lines

```sh
  awk -v pattern="preview" -v today="$today" -v expiryTime="$secondsUntilStale" '
    $1 ~ pattern {
      ... this is exactly the same as your code ...
    }
  '
```

`string ~ pattern` is awk's explicit regex-matching operator.

This will also improve performance as you need to call out to `date` fewer times.

---

This part is making some assumptions:

If you have GNU awk or mawk, there are builtin time functions, so you don't need to call out to `date`

```sh
gawk -v pattern="preview" -v X=3 '
  # convert "YYYY-mm-dd", "HH:MM:SS.sssss" to an epoch value
  function timestamp (date, time) {
    gsub(/-/, " ", date)
    sub(/\.[0-9+]$/, "", time)
    gsub(/:/, " ", time)
    return mktime(date " " time)
  }
  BEGIN {
    # "X" days ago
    expiryTime = systime() - X * 86400
  }
  # skipping the header line, for lines not matching the pattern
  # and where the timestamp is older than X days ago, print the Name
  NR > 1 && $1 !~ pattern && timestamp($4, $5) < expiryTime {print $1}
' releaseListFile
```

which, as of the current time, outputs:

```
app-education-content-creator-1651375038
ci-external-secrets
ci-flux
ci-helm-operator
istio-gateways
```